# How to display mongoose error to backbone views

Tags: validation, backbone.js, express, mongoose, schema

So, I have a backbone view where I am trying to save a user

```
 this.model.save(user_details, { // this is backbone model
                error: function (model, errors) {

                },
                success: function (model, response) {
                }
            });
```

Backbone Model urlRoot points to a backend function where

```
// here user is a Mongoose schema
user.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err.errors);

    }
});
```

I am running some validation in Mongoose schema.

If the validation fails how can I display these "err.errors" on my backbone view. 
I can see at terminal if i console log the errors but not being able to send them back to the views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution after looking through the "errors" object

```
All errors are returned in "errors.resposeText" which has format like
{
  "key name": {
   "message": "",
   "name": "",
   "path": "",
   "type": "",
   "value": ""
 }
}

this.model.save(user_details, { // this is backbone model
            error: function (model, errors) {
                var err = JSON.parse(errors.responseText);
                $.each(errors, function (name, err) {
                   // do something with error
                   console.log(name + err.message);
                }


            },
            success: function (model, response) {
            }
        });
```

NOTE: Errors from mongodb like unique, dup keys are not appended in this format. So its upto us to change them to json and wrap it up in res.errors.

```
In case of error in unique keys user.save(function (err) {

    if (err) {
       if(err.code!='undefined' && err.code=='11000')
           err.errors = {'email':{'message':'This unique value is already in db'}};
       res.send(500, err.errors);
    }
```